# Употребление прилагательного «самый»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, прилагательные, словосочетания

Прилагательное "самый" по смыслу должно сочетаться с прилагательными: "самый интересный", "самый большой".
Однако существует такое словосочетание, как "самый конец".
Ни с какими другими существительными "самый" не сочетается. Правильно ли говорить "самый конец"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ни с какими другими существительными "самый" не сочетается.*
Конечно же, сочетается.

Правильно ли говорить "самый конец"?
Правильно.

Местоимение «самый» является многозначным, поэтому для анализа его сочетаемости с именами существительными необходимо обратиться к толкованию:
[самый](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x), -ая, -ое; ***местоим. прил.***
**2.** Употребляется для уточнения места и времени (обычно с оттенком усиления или предельно высокой степени проявления свойства). *С самого утра. До самой смерти. Над самой головой. У самой воды. Под самыми окнами. Была самая середина лета. С самого начала. **До самого конца**. На самом верху. В самом низу. На самом краю. Как раз самое время учиться. Самая пора обедать. Под самым носом* (разг.; совсем рядом, близко).

Дополнительные примеры с существительными:

*Там, назади, за хребтом гнус мне жить не давал, а тут, у **самого моря**, уже не было ни комаров, ни слепней, ни мошек* (Михаил Пришвин);
*Сержанту пуля угодила в **самое сердце**, и он на месте свалился ничком* (Луи Буссенар);
*...но на другой стороне поляны, в **самой чаще** леса, тонкий дымок, пробираясь сквозь густых ветвей* [*sic*], *обещал ему убежище, а может быть, и защиту* (Михаил Загоскин);
*Мы со Слепым являемся в актовый зал в **самый разгар** событий* (Мариам Петросян).